# Where does normalized texture memory start?

Tags: cuda

If I have a 200 size array in texture memory with linear interpolation enabled, to access the value of the first element I need to access value `0.5`, not `0`. Basically I need to access `desiredValue+0.5`. This ensures that the indexes cover [0-200] inside the image.

How is that with normalized texture memory? are 0-1 the corners of the array, or the element values? to access the first element, would I need to use `0+0.5/200`?

Comment: http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-c-programming-guide/index.html#texture-fetching

Comment: @talonmies thanks, I failed to find that when looking for it. Care to add an answer ?

Comment: It would be just as easy if you wrote one yourself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As seen in the documentation about [Texture Fetching](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-c-programming-guide/index.html#texture-fetching) and specifically seen in the images there:

[image]

`[0-1]` are the corners of the array, so indeed to access a specific array value in normalized units one would need to do `(desiredValue+0.5)/totalSize`